# How to enable VoWiFi (WiFi Calling) programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

I wanted to enable VoWiFi/WiFi calling whenever device gets connect to WiFi SSID.
Is there any android api available to enable/disable VoWiFi or WiFi calling?

Comment: This is a system feature, not available for general developer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android source code reveals that this operation is reserved to system apps only:

```
/**
 * Sets the user's setting for whether or not Voice over WiFi is enabled.
 */
@SystemApi
@RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE)
public void setVoWiFiSettingEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
    .../...
}
```

([Android source code for ImsMmTelManager.java](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/telephony/java/android/telephony/ims/ImsMmTelManager.java;l=973))

The `@SystemApi` tells more:

```
/**
 * Indicates an API is exposed for use by bundled system applications.
 */
```

([Android source code for @SystemApi interface](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/libs/modules-utils/java/android/annotation/SystemApi.java;l=30))

Your application must therefore rely on the user to activate VoWifi.

Hope it helps.